# Does "tous" qualify the subject or the object in this sentence?

Tags: sens, pronoms

> Les humains vous haïssent **tous**, par ignorance.

I’m not sure how to interpret this sentence:

> **All of the humans** hate you.

or

> Humans hate **all of you**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's ambiguous and can be interpreted both ways, but if the author had wanted to be clear that it was qualifying the subject they'd have written

> Tous les humains vous haïssent.

So if I needed to take a guess I'd venture that the intent was to qualify the object, purely based on inference, not grammar.

If, on the other hand, you wanted to clarify without the shadow of a doubt that it is "all of you" who are hated, you would need to work around it a bit, because *Les humains vous haïssent tous* is exactly how you'd say it if a slight doubt was acceptable.

You could say something like:

> Les humains vous haïssent tous autant que vous êtes.
>
> Les humains vous haïssent — vous tous.
>
> Vous êtes tous haïs par les humains.

The first two are slightly more emphatic and the last one uses a passive voice.

Comment: On the other hand, if you want to make it perfectly clear without a shadow of a doubt that "tous" qualifies the objective, how would you modify this sentence? Merci.

Comment: You kind of have to work around it, because the way you have it now is exactly how you'd say it if a slight doubt was acceptable. You could say *Les humains vous haïssent tous autant que vous êtes*, or *Les humains vous haïssent — vous tous*, or *Vous êtes tous haïs par les humains*, but the first two are slightly more emphatic and the last one uses a passive voice.

Comment: (Added into answer)